# Cannot connect to mysql from a GUI client

Tags: mysql, user-interface, debian, virtual-machine

I have a local database on my debian virtual machine. When I ssh into the machine from a Mac and try the following command

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I successfully get connected. However if I try to connect from a GUI client on my Mac with the FQDN of the debian vm I get a ' Connection failed' response.

Also

```
SELECT host, user, password FROM user WHERE user = 'root';
+-----------+------+----------+
| host      | user | password |
+-----------+------+----------+
| localhost | root |          |
| (none)    | root |          |
| 127.0.0.1 | root |          |
| ::1       | root |          |
+-----------+------+----------+
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: Did you add `bind-address=<YOUR-SERVER-IP>` to your `my.conf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have root user with access only from localhost. When you are connecting from ssh - you are connecting locally from debian server. When you are connecting from Mac - this is different host.
You need to [create user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html) with remote access. For example, to allow access from only your Mac

```sql
CREATE USER 'username'@'mac_ip_address'
  IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

or to allow access from all hosts

```sql
CREATE USER 'username'@'%'
  IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```